# bootstrap- place avatar far right of a header with dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a bootstrap project and i've customly designed my header with a text and logo centered.
What i'm finding hard to do right now is how to place and avatar far right inside the header which will serve as a dropdown with the menus account and logout

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="background-color:#215996;height:60px!important;box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #DBDBDB;" align="center" class="col-xs-12">
      <h3 style="color:#FFF"> <img src="img/logo.png" width="30" height="30" align="top"> App Control Panel</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using bootstrap class "navbar-right" you can place something far right to your header

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float-right` class of Bootstarp 4 to slide anything to right. Here's an example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">One <input type="button" class="btn float-right" value="test"></div>
    <div class="col-12">Two <input type="button" class="btn float-right" value="test"></div>
</div>
```